# Getting this error when replying to comment: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error message when I reply to the comment or delete a comment.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in ReplyForm (at CommentReply.js:95)
```

I am not using useEffect hook, still, it's saying **"cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function:"**.
Anyone, please help me with this error!

CommentReply.js

```
import React from "react"
import moment from "moment"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore"

import ReplyForm from "./ReplyForm"

const CommentReply = ({
  comment,
  parentReplies,
  activeComment,
  setActiveComment,
  parentId = null,
}) => {
  const { updateSubCollectionDocument } = useFirestore("solutions")
  const { id: docID } = useParams()

  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  const isReplying =
    activeComment && activeComment.id === comment.id && activeComment.type === "replying"
  const replyId = parentId || comment.id

  // handle sub collection document
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this reply?")) {
      const updatedReplies = parentReplies.filter((reply) => reply.id !== comment.id)
      await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, parentId, {
        replies: updatedReplies,
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="my-4 border border-gray-800 rounded p-4">
      <div className="flex">
        <a
          href={`https://github.com/${comment.user.username}`}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <img
            className="w-12 rounded-full border-2 border-gray-800"
            src={comment.user.avatarURL}
            alt="avatar"
          />
        </a>
        <div className="ml-4 flex-1">
          <p className="text-gray-300 mb-2">
            <a
              href={`https://github.com/${comment.user.username}`}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              {comment.user.displayName
                ? comment.user.displayName
                : comment.user.username}
            </a>
            <small className="pl-2 text-gray-400">
              {moment(comment.createdAt.toDate()).fromNow()}
            </small>
          </p>
          <div className="mt-2 flex">
            {user && (
              <button
                onClick={() => setActiveComment({ id: comment.id, type: "replying" })}
                className="text-gray-400"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-reply"></i>
                <small className="pl-2 font-semibold">Reply</small>
              </button>
            )}
            {user?.uid === comment.user.userID && (
                <button className="text-gray-400" onClick={handleDelete}>
                  <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  <small className="pl-2 font-semibold">Delete</small>
                </button>
            )}
          </div>
          {isReplying && (
            <ReplyForm
              docID={docID}
              replyingTo={comment.user.username}
              id={replyId}
              replies={parentReplies}
              hasCancelButton
              setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CommentReply
```

ReplyForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore"
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"

import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore"

const ReplyForm = ({
  docID,
  replyingTo,
  id,
  commentID,
  replies,
  setActiveComment,
  initialText = "",
  isReply,
  hasCancelButton = false,
}) => {
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState(initialText)
  const { updateSubCollectionDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const commentToAdd = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        content: newComment.trim(),
        reactions: [],
        replyingTo,
        parentID: id,
        user: {
          userID: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        },
        createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
      }

      if (!isReply && initialText) {
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          content: newComment,
        })
      } else if (isReply && initialText) {
        const reply = replies.find((reply) => reply.id === commentID)
        if (reply) reply.content = newComment
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          replies: replies,
        })
      } else {
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          replies: [...replies, commentToAdd],
        })
      }
      setActiveComment(false)
      setNewComment("")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="reply">
        <textarea
          className="bg-transparent text-white font-semibold border border-gray-800 rounded w-full p-4 mt-6 outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-purple-500"
          name="reply"
          id="reply"
          cols="30"
          rows="4"
          placeholder="Start Typing..."
          required
          onChange={(e) => setNewComment(e.target.value)}
          value={newComment}
        ></textarea>
      </label>
      <div className="flex">
        <button
          className={`self-end ${
            response.isPending
              ? "bg-indigo-500 cursor-not-allowed"
              : "bg-purple-800 transition-all duration-200 bg-gradient-to-br hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-indigo-500"
          } mt-4 p-3 text-white text-base font-heading font-semibold shadow-md rounded focus:outline-none`}
          disabled={response.isPending}
        >
          Reply
        </button>
        {hasCancelButton && (
          <button
            onClick={() => setActiveComment(false)}
            type="button"
            className={`self-end bg-purple-800 transition-all duration-200 bg-gradient-to-br hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-indigo-500 mt-4 ml-4 p-3 text-white text-base font-heading font-semibold shadow-md rounded focus:outline-none`}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ReplyForm
```

SolutionComments.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection"

import Comment from "./Comment"
import CommentForm from "./CommentForm"

const SolutionComments = () => {
  const [activeComment, setActiveComment] = useState(null)
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { documents } = useCollection(`solutions/${id}/comments`, null, 4, [
    "createdAt",
    "desc",
  ])

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <CommentForm docID={id} />
      <div>
        {documents &&
          documents.map((comment) => (
            <Comment
              key={comment.id}
              comment={comment}
              replies={comment.replies}
              activeComment={activeComment}
              setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SolutionComments
```

Comment.js

```
import React from "react"
import moment from "moment"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore"

import CommentReply from "./CommentReply"
import ReplyForm from "./ReplyForm"

const Comment = ({
  comment,
  replies,
  activeComment,
  setActiveComment,
  parentId = null,
}) => {
  const { deleteSubCollectionDocument } = useFirestore("solutions")
  const { id: docID } = useParams()
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  const isEditing =
    activeComment && activeComment.id === comment.id && activeComment.type === "editing"
  const isReplying =
    activeComment && activeComment.id === comment.id && activeComment.type === "replying"
  const replyId = parentId || comment.id

  // handle sub collection document
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this comment?")) {
      await deleteSubCollectionDocument(docID, comment.id)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="my-4 border border-gray-800 rounded p-4">
      <div className="flex">
        <a
          href={`https://github.com/${comment.user.username}`}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <img
            className="w-12 rounded-full border-2 border-gray-800"
            src={comment.user.avatarURL}
            alt="avatar"
          />
        </a>
        <div className="ml-4 flex-1">
          <p className="text-gray-300 mb-2">
            <a
              href={`https://github.com/${comment.user.username}`}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              {comment.user.displayName
                ? comment.user.displayName
                : comment.user.username}
            </a>
            <small className="pl-2 text-gray-400">
              {moment(comment.createdAt.toDate()).fromNow()}
            </small>
          </p>
          <div className="mt-2 flex">
            {user && (
              <button
                onClick={() => setActiveComment({ id: comment.id, type: "replying" })}
                className="text-gray-400"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-reply"></i>
                <small className="pl-2 font-semibold">Reply</small>
              </button>
            )}
            {user?.uid === comment.user.userID && (
              <>
                <button className="text-gray-400" onClick={handleDelete}>
                  <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  <small className="pl-2 font-semibold">Delete</small>
                </button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
          {isReplying && (
            <ReplyForm
              docID={docID}
              replyingTo={comment.user.username}
              id={replyId}
              replies={replies}
              hasCancelButton
              setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
            />
          )}
          {replies &&
            replies
              .sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.seconds - b.createdAt.seconds)
              .map((reply) => (
                <CommentReply
                  key={reply.id}
                  comment={reply}
                  parentReplies={replies}
                  parentId={comment.id}
                  activeComment={activeComment}
                  setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
                />
              ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about functional component in your snippets calling `setActiveComment(false)` from parent component, state `isActive` must be used for Conditional Rendering of `CommentReply.js`. And next call `setNewComment("")` is within same component.
These re render will unmount child component on which it can not perform `setNewComment("")`.

---

**If it is, the fix can be,**
You better remove `setNewComment("")` and put it in `useEffect()` with empty dependency array to set empty string when component mounts first time and not on re-render.

**ReplyForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore"
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"

import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore"

const ReplyForm = ({
  docID,
  replyingTo,
  id,
  commentID,
  replies,
  setActiveComment,
  initialText = "",
  isReply,
  hasCancelButton = false,
}) => {
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState(initialText)
  const { updateSubCollectionDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  useEffect(()=>{
    setNewComment("");
  },[]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const commentToAdd = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        content: newComment.trim(),
        reactions: [],
        replyingTo,
        parentID: id,
        user: {
          userID: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        },
        createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
      }

      if (!isReply && initialText) {
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          content: newComment,
        })
      } else if (isReply && initialText) {
        const reply = replies.find((reply) => reply.id === commentID)
        if (reply) reply.content = newComment
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          replies: replies,
        })
      } else {
        await updateSubCollectionDocument(docID, id, {
          replies: [...replies, commentToAdd],
        })
      }
      setActiveComment(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="reply">
        <textarea
          className="bg-transparent text-white font-semibold border border-gray-800 rounded w-full p-4 mt-6 outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-purple-500"
          name="reply"
          id="reply"
          cols="30"
          rows="4"
          placeholder="Start Typing..."
          required
          onChange={(e) => setNewComment(e.target.value)}
          value={newComment}
        ></textarea>
      </label>
      <div className="flex">
        <button
          className={`self-end ${
            response.isPending
              ? "bg-indigo-500 cursor-not-allowed"
              : "bg-purple-800 transition-all duration-200 bg-gradient-to-br hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-indigo-500"
          } mt-4 p-3 text-white text-base font-heading font-semibold shadow-md rounded focus:outline-none`}
          disabled={response.isPending}
        >
          Reply
        </button>
        {hasCancelButton && (
          <button
            onClick={() => setActiveComment(false)}
            type="button"
            className={`self-end bg-purple-800 transition-all duration-200 bg-gradient-to-br hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-indigo-500 mt-4 ml-4 p-3 text-white text-base font-heading font-semibold shadow-md rounded focus:outline-none`}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ReplyForm
```

Comment: It fixed an issue but I have one more issue when I delete the reply or a parent comment it shows me the same error message: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Comment (at SolutionComments.js:23)`

Comment: it must be the same issue in `SolutionCommets.js` component where you must be trying to update the child component state after it is unmounted.

Comment: I just added code for SolutionComments.js, please check

Comment: I tried to find the bug but unfortunately not able to find that.